# Xamarin Can I use Appium to perform automation testing with a real device?

Tags: xamarin, automation, appium

Can I use Appium with Xamarin, to run automation tests on a real device?
I need to test bluetooth connectivity among the basic functions of the app (login, navigation etc), that is why I need to use a real device.

Is this possible? And any information that is helpful towards how to achieve that is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video about Appium-based automated mobile UI testing in xamarin you can refer to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffxtOUCIUUQ.

And there is a sample in it you can test with:https://github.com/xamarin-automation-service/Appium.POP.Example